# Extract numbers from a string in java

Tags: java, regex, string, numbers

I want to extract numbers from a string like:

```
str="good_mor9ni13ng_23guys ";
```

The output should be an array `[9,13,23]`.
How should I proceed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+").matcher("good_mor9ni13ng_23guys");
while (m.find()) {
    matches.add(m.group());
}
```

Comment: I would prefer `\d++`, but this will certainly work (+1).

Comment: @BoristheSpider yes \\d+ would be shorter. thanks

Comment: No, I meant `\d++` - the possessive quantifier.